# Expanding the background color rectangle of selected text

Tags: css

According to MDN, outline should work on the `::selection` pseudoelement, yet it doesn't seem to when tested on both chrome and ff.

```css
::selection {
  background-color:red;
  outline:2px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
My cool text, select me!
```

I'm creating a text editor and basically it just annoys me how tight fitting the selection background color is. I want to expand it a few pixels and outline would be the right attribute for the job but it doesn't work?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the MDN is wrong or not updated, because if we refer to [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-pseudo-4/#selectordef-selection):

> The highlight pseudo-elements can only be styled by a limited set of properties that do not affect layout. The following properties apply to the highlight pseudo-elements:
>
> - color
> - background-color
> - cursor
> - caret-color
> - text-decoration and its associated properties
> - text-shadow
> - stroke-color, fill-color, and stroke-width

The `outline` isn't listed which explain why it's not working. Also I don't think you can control the hightlighting area. As explained in the same specification:

> For text, the corresponding overlay must cover **at least the entire em box** and may extend further above/below the em box **to the line box edges**. Spacing between two characters may also be part of the overlay area, in which case it belongs to the innermost element that contains both characters and is selected when both characters are selected.

We already have the em box which is trivial and your best luck is to have more in case the line box is higher but it **will not** behave the same cross browser.

Here is a basic example where I use a pseudo element with a big font-size to increase the height of the line-box and I align it in the middle. In this case the selection will cover more than the text but of course this will also affect the layout which is probably not needed and will not work with all the browser.

*The below example works on Chrome and doesn't on Fiferfox*

```css
p:after {
  content: "";
  font-size: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

p::selection {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>My cool text, select me!</p>
```

Another important thing is that all the properties applied inside that area cannot overflow it. We know that with `text-shadow` we can place the shadow far from the text but with the selection it won't be possible because it cannot overflow the hightlighting area:

```css
p {
  text-shadow:0 10px 0 red;
}

p::selection {
  background-color: red;
  text-shadow:0 -10px 0 blue;
}
```

```html
<p>My cool text, select me!</p>
```

Notice how the blue text-shadow is partially visible like we have applied `overflow:hidden` to the red area. So even if you are able to style the selection with outline it's basically impossible to control its dimension which is what you need here.

---

I think your best option is to rely on JS to create dynamic element or wrap selected text to easily style them. With the CSS, you can only apply some hack that will affect your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Outside the first line, the other line is valid with `line-height`. As you can see:

```css
div {
  line-height:30px;
}

div::selection {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>text<br />text<br />text</div>
```

So, I did a Javascript trick that added the first line for us. I'm also giving `font-size: 0px` for the first line. So our problem is solved. As you can see:

```js
let a = document.querySelectorAll(".a");

a.forEach(function(par){
  par.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin','needed text<br />')
})

// for an unseen first line.
```

```css
.a {
  line-height:50px;    
}

.a::selection {
  background: yellow;
}

.a::first-line {
  font-size:0px;
  line-height:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">text</div>
```